# CakePHP - Select record by other column instead of ID

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I am using CakePHP v2.2 and I need to query the table using another column instead of the id.

Here is my controller code:

```
public function view($id = null){
    $this->layout = 'clean';
    $sku = array('Image.sku' => $id);
    $this->Image->find('first', array('conditions' => $sku));
    $this->set('image', $this->Image->read());
}
```

View

```
header('Content-type: ' . $image['Image']['type']);
header('Content-length: ' . $image['Image']['size']);
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $image['Image']['name'].'"');
echo $image['Image']['content'];
```

I want to use the sku as the parameter for the query and not the id. Can I do that without modifying my table? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have **sku** column in your table, you can do this:

```
$this->Image->findBySku('first'...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$image = $this->Image->find('first', array('conditions' => $sku));
$this->set('image', $image);
```